# How to get HTML5 canvas text to show html entity?

Tags: html, canvas, html-entities

I'm parsing an xml file that stores image/caption data both of which I need to display on my canvas.  However occasionally there's an entity in the file and when drawing the text to the canvas it interprets it as flat text.  How can i get `&copy;` to show up as © on the canvas?  Is this even possible, or does anyone know of a good work around?

Answer (score 5):

You could replace the HTML entities with their equivalent unicode characters.

E.g.

```
var x = 'This is &copy; 2010';
x = x.replace( /&copy;/, '\u00A9' ); // x is now 'This is © 2010'
```

Comment: Thanks! My degree symbols were showing as a square, and &deg; was showing as text...and then I tried \u00B0 which solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that all the HTML entities will be having the hex values

example for ℃ Hex value is "2103" we can convert it as "\u2103" and add it to canvas code

```
    <canvas id='my-canvas'></canvas>
    <script>
    var c = document.getElementById("my-canvas");  
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.strokeText("170 \u2103", 25, 50);
    ctx.stroke();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Late, but for others searching for a solution:

```js
var inputText = 'This is &copy; 2010';

var textContainer = document.createElement('span'); // Use a span to render the html entities
textContainer.innerHTML = inputText; // Set as innerhtml to make sure entities are converted

var outputText = textContainer.textContent; // x is now 'This is © 2010'
```

The input text is rendered just like normal text in html elements. This automatically converts all html entities.

Comment: @RuudVerhoef i thought the code was pretty self-explanatory, but updated with some comments to clarify. ;)

Comment: This is the best answer!