# HTML5 Canvas Math square root & power approach

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Is there any efficient way to write a square root number(radical sign) or a power in a html5 canvas?

The values come from an object which could look like this:

```
squarevalues = ["3",{type:"power", base:"27",pow:"3"},{type:"radical", radvalue:"4"}]
```

I tried using

```
ctx.fillText("√"+squarevalues[2].radvalue+"", leftpos, toppos);
```

and then drawing a line above the number. But this is very tedious work and probably not going to work because the font size is changed for all square roots/powers to make filltext have the same width whatever the length of the content.

Is there any other solution possible to draw these efficiently?

Comment: check this out http://www.mathjax.org/

Comment: How about just using a mathematics font that includes superscripts, sqRoot symbol, etc?

Comment: I'm interested in doing this inside the canvas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get HTML5 canvas text to show html entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653877/how-to-get-html5-canvas-text-to-show-html-entity)